# Zephyr device tree: how to get the values of the named properties of a phandle behind a phandles, for all compatible nodes?

Tags: zephyr-rtos

In my Zephyr DTS binding I have a node with a given compatibility, let's call it `my_compatibilty`, with an optional property of type `phandles`, let's call it `things`,  allowed to have up to two elements.  In my driver code I can build up an array of the leaves of this tree; for instance, I can make an array of the values of a string entry `flibble` within `things`, or `NULL` if not present, for all compatible nodes with:

```
#define GET_THINGS_LIST(i, name) {DT_PROP_BY_PHANDLE_IDX_OR(i, things, 0, name, NULL),  \
                                  DT_PROP_BY_PHANDLE_IDX_OR(i, things, 1, name, NULL)},

static const char *const leafValueFlibble[][2] = {
    DT_FOREACH_STATUS_OKAY_VARGS(my_compatibilty, GET_THINGS_LIST, flibble)
};
```

This is now easy to manage, a nice ordered list I can work with from C.

HOWEVER, I now need `flibble` to be a `phandle`-type property.  How do I extend the macrobatics above so that I can still get at the leaves of the tree, i.e. for all compatible nodes, create arrays of the values of the named properties within `flibble` (or `NULL`/`-1`/`some-known-value` if not present to keep the order)?

Comment: For clarity, you have a devicetree with nodes compatible with `my_compatible` which may or may not contain a property `thing` which if present contains phandles to nodes which may contain property `flibble` which if present is a pgandle to another node whose properties you want to form an array from? Do we know the properties of this last node? Is it possible this node will contain `flibble` and we want to follow it all the way down? On top of this, if we ever don't find what we are looking for at a node, we need to provide a default empty entry?

Comment: That is correct: `thing` is optional in the `my_compatible` nodes and `flibble` is optional inside `thing` but, fortunately, all of the elements of `flibble` (there are only two, we might call them `bingInt` and `bingString`) are _not_ optional, I simply need to be able to populate the array with their values. `fibble` will never, itself, contain `flibble` and, since none of the elements in`flibble` are optional there is no need for a default there.

Comment: Just to be clear, when making the C array of, say, `bingInt` in all of the `my_compatible` nodes then if it is absent because `thing` is absent or `flibble` is absent then I do need a default since I need all my arrays, the leaves of the tree, to be indexable in the same way.